# PhonePe returning null to onActivityResult by using Intent flow UPI integration

Tags: android, android-intent, payment, upi

I am using Intent flow UPI integration in app, everything works fine for googlepay and paytm, but on using phonepe ,(after successfull payment) when control returns to my app after in onActivityResult method Intent data is null(not in case of googlepay and paytm), and i am not getting response,and all details in it.
and Thanks,if you can help me with this.

i am following this tutorial :-
https://medium.com/@Abdulkadir98/integrating-upi-payments-inside-your-android-app-514d800d5baa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution for this. Everything is fine in code but for `phonepe 
.appendQueryParameter("tr", "261433")`
this one is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the URI that you're sending as the intent. Also, it would be nice to see the code snippet in order to understand the problem fully.